# Getting "permission denied" when serving a Firebase Hosting site locally

Tags: node.js, firebase-hosting

Im new to Firebase Hosting and trying to serve a pre-existing project locally but get the following error:

```
[debug] [2018-10-11T13:26:23.359Z] Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/logs'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at Object.assertLogsPath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/emulator/logs.js:65:10)
    at new Controller (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator/src/cli/controller.js:77:32)
    at FunctionsEmulator.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/functionsEmulator.js:113:21)
    at Object.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/serve/functions.js:9:29)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/serve/index.js:17:21
    at arrayMap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:639:23)
    at Function.map (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9556:14)
    at _serve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/serve/index.js:15:7)
    at Command._action (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/commands/serve.js:47:12)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks to be an issue on github https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/760

Comment: Here is a link for preventing permission errors https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions